# Some breakpoints not hit Eclipse ADT

Tags: eclipse, adt, breakpoints

I have 4 breakpoints but only 2 are getting hit. What I notice is that the breakpoints getting get hit show a small check mark in the breakpoints view.
What does this check mark mean and how can I activate my other breakpoints?

[image: Eclipse Breakpoints view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. This is an issue where breakpoints other than on the main thread are not hit. This is an exclusive problem on the Samsung Galaxy S5 under Lollipop.

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/android-studio-does-not-stop-on-some-breakpoints-when-connected-to-samsung-galaxy-s5-with-lollipop-5/202/277622?boardName=General&listLines=15&startId=zzzzz~

Answer (score 1):

There is some explanation of the various symbols here:

[What different breakpoint icons mean in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079000/what-different-breakpoint-annotations-mean-in-eclipse)

I've just tried it myself and it appears that your breakpoints are not disabled, but the little check mark only appears once you're actually executing the function that the breakpoint is in. So the reason your breakpoints aren't hit, is because there is no code path that leads into the code you're trying to debug, i.e. you're not calling it.

Comment: You are basically correct about the check marks. But in fact this is a super odd issue. Breakpoints are 100% in executed code. I can see this because I can output changing log messages. That some breakpoints are missed happens only on the Lollipop Galaxy S5. Same code on the Galaxy S3 hits all the breakpoints. Happens on Android Studio as well as on Eclipse. Somethings really messed up.